# Knowing when a photo is deleted with Flickr API

Tags: web-services, rest, flickr

In my application, I have to run a periodical job where I need data about all the photos on my client's Flickr account. Currently, I perform several calls to flickr.photos.search to retrieve meta about all the photos each time.
What I ask is: is there a way to be get informed by Flickr when a photo is modified or deleted, so that I don't need to retrieve metas for each photos, but rather store theme once, and only download what has changed since the last time I run the job ?
Thx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such notification possible from the Flickr API to your code.

What you can do on the other hand is (recommended only if volume for change of photo metadata is high) -

Setup a cron job which would scan through the photos and store if the photo id's are deleted or not - which can be used later.

Comment: I already have such a job, which is run once a day. Currently it download metas about all photos (with few calls to flickr.photos.search), and it rebuild the database each time. The solution you suggest require one api call per photo, which is way too much. I'm seeking for a solution which lower the amount of api traffic.

Comment: @fokenrute Interesting. [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) does not have any functions for batch processing. IMHO following strategy can be helpful (just a thought)  -- You can parse the RSS feed of users latest photos? - which should give you the details in one go!

Comment: Yes but I need to know if a pĥoto has been deleted. Otherwise, I might compute bad results because some of my data should no longer be taken into account. Are photos deletion notified in the RSS feed ?